# Magento: improving search engine (inflections, irrelevant words removal, etc.)

Tags: php, magento

I'm interested in knowing if I can detect inflections (e.g. dogs/dog), remove non-important words ("made in the usa" -> "in" and "the" are not important), etc. in the search string entered by the user for the Magento search engine without hard-coding such many scenarios in one big PHP code block. I can process this search string to a certain degree, but it will look unsanitary and ugly.

Any suggestions or pointers for making it an "intelliegent" search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Use this class:

```
class Inflection
{
    static $plural = array(
    '/(quiz)$/i' => "$1zes",
    '/^(ox)$/i' => "$1en",
    '/([m|l])ouse$/i' => "$1ice",
    '/(matr|vert|ind)ix|ex$/i' => "$1ices",
    '/(x|ch|ss|sh)$/i' => "$1es",
    '/([^aeiouy]|qu)y$/i' => "$1ies",
    '/(hive)$/i' => "$1s",
    '/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/i' => "$1$2ves",
    '/(shea|lea|loa|thie)f$/i' => "$1ves",
    '/sis$/i' => "ses",
    '/([ti])um$/i' => "$1a",
    '/(tomat|potat|ech|her|vet)o$/i'=> "$1oes",
    '/(bu)s$/i' => "$1ses",
    '/(alias)$/i' => "$1es",
    '/(octop)us$/i' => "$1i",
    '/(ax|test)is$/i' => "$1es",
    '/(us)$/i' => "$1es",
    '/s$/i' => "s",
    '/$/' => "s"
    );

    static $singular = array(
    '/(quiz)zes$/i' => "$1",
    '/(matr)ices$/i' => "$1ix",
    '/(vert|ind)ices$/i' => "$1ex",
    '/^(ox)en$/i' => "$1",
    '/(alias)es$/i' => "$1",
    '/(octop|vir)i$/i' => "$1us",
    '/(cris|ax|test)es$/i' => "$1is",
    '/(shoe)s$/i' => "$1",
    '/(o)es$/i' => "$1",
    '/(bus)es$/i' => "$1",
    '/([m|l])ice$/i' => "$1ouse",
    '/(x|ch|ss|sh)es$/i' => "$1",
    '/(m)ovies$/i' => "$1ovie",
    '/(s)eries$/i' => "$1eries",
    '/([^aeiouy]|qu)ies$/i' => "$1y",
    '/([lr])ves$/i' => "$1f",
    '/(tive)s$/i' => "$1",
    '/(hive)s$/i' => "$1",
    '/(li|wi|kni)ves$/i' => "$1fe",
    '/(shea|loa|lea|thie)ves$/i'=> "$1f",
    '/(^analy)ses$/i' => "$1sis",
    '/((a)naly|(b)a|(d)iagno|(p)arenthe|(p)rogno|(s)ynop|(t)he)ses$/i' => "$1$2sis",
    '/([ti])a$/i' => "$1um",
    '/(n)ews$/i' => "$1ews",
    '/(h|bl)ouses$/i' => "$1ouse",
    '/(corpse)s$/i' => "$1",
    '/(us)es$/i' => "$1",
    '/s$/i' => ""
    );

    static $irregular = array(
    'move' => 'moves',
    'foot' => 'feet',
    'goose' => 'geese',
    'sex' => 'sexes',
    'child' => 'children',
    'man' => 'men',
    'tooth' => 'teeth',
    'person' => 'people',
    'admin' => 'admin'
    );

    static $uncountable = array(
    'sheep',
    'fish',
    'deer',
    'series',
    'species',
    'money',
    'rice',
    'information',
    'equipment'
    );

    public static function pluralize( $string )
    {
global $irregularWords;

// save some time in the case that singular and plural are the same
    if ( in_array( strtolower( $string ), self::$uncountable ) )
        return $string;

    // check for irregular singular forms
    foreach ( $irregularWords as $pattern => $result )
    {
        $pattern = '/' . $pattern . '$/i';

        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) )
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $string);
    }

    // check for irregular singular forms
    foreach ( self::$irregular as $pattern => $result )
    {
        $pattern = '/' . $pattern . '$/i';

        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) )
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $string);
    }

    // check for matches using regular expressions
    foreach ( self::$plural as $pattern => $result )
    {
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) )
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $string );
    }

    return $string;
    }

    public static function singularize( $string )
    {   
global $irregularWords;
    // save some time in the case that singular and plural are the same
    if ( in_array( strtolower( $string ), self::$uncountable ) )
        return $string;

// check for irregular words
    foreach ( $irregularWords as $result => $pattern )
    {
        $pattern = '/' . $pattern . '$/i';

        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) )
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $string);
    }

// check for irregular plural forms
    foreach ( self::$irregular as $result => $pattern )
    {
        $pattern = '/' . $pattern . '$/i';

        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) )
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $string);
    }

// check for matches using regular expressions
    foreach ( self::$singular as $pattern => $result )
    {
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) )
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $string );
    }

    return $string;
    }

    public static function pluralize_if($count, $string)
    {
    if ($count == 1)
        return "1 $string";
    else
        return $count . " " . self::pluralize($string);
    }
}
```

And if you have a time use a standard way for inflection usage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection

You can as array combine with XML so put all inflections data, look at how codeigniter has inflection very friendly: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/inflector_helper.html

Many frameworks supports built-in inflections but it will focus only in mainly English only. For other languages you should write own... or use unicode.org with some inflections standards for other languages if you need it.